# Uploading and streaming video from Azure

Tags: azure, video-encoding

I am wondering if it is possible to host videos on the azure platform.  Does Azure allow encoding videos using expression encoders before storing them as a blob.  I am imaging a process/architecture where video is upload via client, saved to a location on azure and queued up.  A process runs to pick it up from queue, encode it and save it as a blob.  Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that there are services in azure today for video encoding. Could be a good business idea to write an app to do this.

You could load the video up to azure, then have another service that downloaded the video, encoded it, and sent it up to the cloud again. The major problem with this approach is the bandwidth cost that you would incurr.